# Best book for vocabulary building through etymology

Tags: discussion, resources, etymology

Could you hint the best etymology book?

I'd like to learn new words via their origin.

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=etymology

Comment: Hard to say which is the best. The OED http://www.oed.com/ provides also reliable  etymological information but there are other books which focus on the etymology of words such as “Word Origins”, by A. Liberman, for instance https://books.google.it/books/about/Word_Origins_and_How_We_Know_Them.html?id=TINbsgUyGzQC&redir_esc=y

Comment: You might get more helpful candidate books over at [English Language Learners.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com) or at [Language Learning.SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com).  Also, just googling for 'vocabulary building etymology' will get you a lot of online resources and apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Norman Lewis: *Word Power Made Easy* is one of the best books.

[Good reads review](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/827597.Word_Power_Made_Easy)

Answer (score 0):

There is no best book.

Parts of this book are available on line:

Gold, David L. 2009. *Studies in Etymology and Etiology (With Emphasis on Germanic, Jewish, Romance, and Slavic Languages)*. Selected and edited, with a foreword, by Félix Rodríguez González and Antonio Lillo Buades. Alicante. Publicaciones de la Universidad de Alicante.

On reflection, I realize that you need something other than a book on etymology.

If you have in mind expanding your vocabulary (by learning words coined at any time in the past or now), you need a book that will give you the meanings of prefixes and suffixes that are used to form words.

Try this one:

Robert Schleifer's Grow Your Vocabulary By Learning the Roots of English Words

If you have in mind expanding your vocabulary by learning newly coined words, try this

Barnhart Dictionary of New English (at least three volumes)

The Barnhart Dictionary Companion

Comment: On reflection, I must correct my answer. You do not need a book on etymology.

Comment: David L. Gold, actually, yes) I'm looking for not good etymology books only, but books which help me to remember words and phrases via understandind(!), etymology books are just a part of these concept). In general, I'm interesred in different stories which explain words' origin in a popular form. It looks like interesting stories about words, something like that. May be, you could give me some tips - I mean, some recommendations)? These books aren't widely known as usual. They are famous in "linguistic circles". That's why I'm asking there.☺ Thank you in advance!